# Link Aaccess table with Excel using vba TransferSpreadsheet

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access, sharepoint

I am trying to link Excel with SharePoint to be able to read/write in SharePoint using Excel.

I tried many ways but I always get an error "cannot connect to the server", so I tried to link SharePoint with  a table in MS Access instead and it worked using "TransferSharePointList".

Now, to workaround this error in Excel, I am going to link that table in MS Access with excel. I tried using `TransferSpreadsheet` but I have the table in Excel empty and in Access like the attached photo.

Below is my code in MS Access:

```
    DoCmd.TransferSharePointList acLinkSharePointList, SERVER, LISTNAME, VIEWNAME, TableName, True
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acLink, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "Prices", "C:\Users\Desktop\1.xlsx", True
    CurrentDb.TableDefs.Refresh
End Sub
```

Could anyone tell me why I am getting the table empty in Excel.

[image]

Comment: Have you put anything into the Excel table?  It will be empty if you haven't.  (Or is your question trying to say that you are attempting to link the single Access table, "Prices", to two different sources??  If so, that isn't going to work - Access won't know which source it should use.)

Comment: No I haven't , I want to link an access table to excel i.e edit the access table from excel , I also tried this code without sharepoint (Access has only one source which is Excel) and it's still not working

Comment: What you have done is fine then - your Access table is linked to the Excel spreadsheet, and you can edit the table from Excel.  After editing, go back into Access and your table will reflect the changes.

Comment: Thanks YowE3K , the problem is that I dont see any table in Excel , Just a blank sheet

Comment: Until you enter information, that blank sheet **is** your table.  Your Access code says you will have field names in row 1, so that is the first step - put those field names in.  The second step is to put data in rows 2 onwards.

Comment: Yes got it , thanks  YowE3K !

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the Sheet name:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acLink, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "Prices", "C:\Users\Desktop\1.xlsx", True, "Sheet1$"   '<-- Sheet name
CurrentDb.TableDefs.Refresh
```

Comment: I tried it and it is still not working (I think the sheet and range will only be needed in case of "acImport"

Answer (score 0):

I think it's like this.

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet, acLink, , "xlData", strFileName, True
```

See the URL below for more info.

http://access-excel.tips/access-vba-cocmd-transferspreadsheet/